# Questions about IDEs

Tags: discussion

Are questions about IDEs (integrated development environments) considered to be relevant to programmers.stackexchange.com, or would such questions be more relevant at Super user or Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow is the one that [specifically mentions software tools](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), so that's probably the most appropriate site.

Comment: Our [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) explicitly mentions that questions about programming tools are off topic, and should be asked on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: Fair enough.  Edited.